# Is the filtration of inertia group a strict one?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Given a local field K and its finite galois extension L (we have non-archimedean valuation $v_{K}$ and $v_{L}$). We define $\Gamma=Gal(L/K)$, and for $i\in \mathbb{Z}$, we can define $\Gamma_{i}$ (the $\Gamma_{0}$ is the inertia group). I want to know if  $\Gamma_{i}$ is nontrivial, whether it strictly contains $\Gamma_{i+1}$ or not?

---

Here is the definition of $\Gamma_{i}$$:=$$\{\gamma\in\Gamma|v_{L}(x\gamma-x)\geq i+1 ,\forall x\in R_{L}\}$, $R_{L}$ is the valuation ring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the inclusion of $\Gamma_{i+1}$ in $\Gamma_i$ is often an equality.  The simplest example is $K=\mathbf{Q}_2$, $L=\mathbf{Q}_2(\sqrt2)$.  Here $\Gamma=\Gamma_0=\Gamma_1=\Gamma_2$, and $\Gamma_3$ is trivial.

It is possible to find a $K$ and a degree-$p$ cyclic extension $L$ of $K$ (where $p$ is the residual characteristic) such that the length of the filtration is any preassigned number $\not\equiv0\pmod p$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Chandan! I a student majoring in algebraic geometry, and recently study some number theory, can you give me some reference for the Herbrand Fuction?  The definition is a little bit puzzling

Comment: Perhaps the best place to read about it is the book by Serre on Local Fields.